# No git trees, why?

Tags: git, path, tree, branch

I'm new with git and I don't understand one thing.

I create a repository and a master branch.
I made an initial commit with lot of files.
I created a branch "`development`".
And from `development` branch a new branch for a new project.
I made some commit, push.
But all my git history is flat. Why ?

Why I look at other repository there is path tree like this:

[image: log graph]

Why mine still flat?
When the pat tree start to show different branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why mine still flat? When the pat tree start to show different branches?

It starts branching out in earnest when you are making *concurrent* commits on different branches.

Meaning you need to make commits both on master *and* dev *and* newbranch to see a tree.

If not, if you just had commits (even though they are in successive branches), the graph of commits remains flat.

```
git init .
git add and commit on master:

m--m--m (master)
```

Then create branch dev:

```
git checkout -b dev
# add and commit on dev

m--m--m--d--d--d (dev)
```

Finally, new branch:

```
m--m--m--d--d--d--b--b (newbranch)
      |        |
    (master) (dev)
```

If you go back to master dev and makes new commits, *then* you start to see a tree:

```
git checkout master
# new commits

git checkout dev
# new commits

m--m--m--M--M (master)
       \
        d--d--d--D--D (dev)
               \
                b--bb (newbranch)
```

See it [with commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/6309) like:

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --all
```